# Hibernate 4 Validator with Hibernate 3 validation annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

Having the standardized Validator from the *javax* package created like in the manual

```
 Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

it won't recognize old validator annotations from the *org.hibernate.validator* package, is there any option to get them work with the hibernate 4 validator without refactoring the whole project?

We used hibernate 3 until we decided to migrate our project to hibernate 4. While using the *org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator* for the moment, it is not possible to use this class with hibernate 4 validator due to standardization.

So does someone have any possible solution how to stick with the old validator annotations, but still get classes validated within the project scope without refactoring and modifying the whole sourcecode? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You will have to migrate your annotations/constraints. The Hibernate Validator 3 code base is obsolete and no further development occurs on this version of Validator.

Hibernate Validator 4.x (and later) release does not recognize Validator 3 annotations as Bean Validation constraints. These constraints do not contain the required constraint marker annotation.

Migrating the annotation should really not be a big problem. In most cases you should be able to just change the package.

Comment: bad to hear. but we managed the refactoring in some hours. thank you anyway for the answer.